# Change integer value with string in array on some conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the one of many code challenges from one company that they gave me to solve.

Write a program that outputs sequentially the integers from 1 to 99, but on some conditions:
- when the integer is a multiple of 3 print “Open” instead of the number
- when it is a multiple of 7 print “Source” instead of the number
- when it is a multiple of both 3 and 7 print “OpenSource” instead of the number

I'v wrote this chunk of code:

```js
let array = []

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    array.push(i);
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        array[i] = "open";
    }
    if (i % 7 === 0) {
        array[i] = "source";
    }
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 7 === 0) {
        array[i] = "opensource";
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

As you can see from the output, something is messy at index 2-3. All other integers are replaced correctly.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: you have made a mistake... array indexes start from 0, so your loop start is wrong, and so indexing with `[i]` is also wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array's first index is 0 not 1. So either insert in arr[i - 1] or use the following approach to fix your issue.

**Reasoning of my solution** - The loop will start from 1 in my case as we want to check from 0 to 100. And after that, I check the logic if the current value(value) is multiple of 3 or 7 or both. And after that, just push the value into the array and it will automatically add the values in respective indexes.

In your scenario - we need to do arr[index - 1] to compensate the difference between current value and index.

```js
let array = []

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    let value = i;
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        value = "open";
    }
    if (i % 7 === 0) {
        value = "source";
    }
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 7 === 0) {
        value = "opensource";
    }
    array.push(value);
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: This is the right and most elegant solution for the task given, I would say. Thank you very much. The loop can start at any number, right? In this case it must start with 1 in order to get the array starting with the 1 as required in the task, not the zero. As you said, if I add `array[i -1]` in the every if statement block, the result will be correct as well. That -1 is needed to compensate the difference between the index enumeration which start always at 0 and the loop values that start with the 1?

Comment: Also, I'm not get it, why someone has give the negative vote for this question, as that is the one of the questions from many similar I have got from one company as test. I would be grateful if you could please clarify all of this as well. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Added the explanaton.

Answer (score -1):

If you debug the code, you'll notice, that the first three values are undefined:

```js
let array = []

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  array.push(i);
  if (i < 10) {
    console.log(i, i % 3, i % 7, array[i]);
  }

  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    array[i] = "open";
  }
  if (i % 7 === 0) {
    array[i] = "source";
  }
  if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 7 === 0) {
    array[i] = "opensource";
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

So you'll need to fix your indexing logic.